# Segmentation Fault: 11 with Scanf

Tags: arrays, c, macos, segmentation-fault, scanf

I have the following code:

```
#include "Analysis.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    FILE *TS;
//Input Files
    TS = fopen("IceDat2C.dat","r");
//Parametrization
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;;
    double temp,tscale;
    int points = 3606930
    double T[points],A[points],sd[points];
    int n[points];

    fscanf(TS,"%d %lf %lf %lf\n",&n[j],&A[j],&T[j],&sd[j]);
    return 1;
}
```

The program will return the seg. fault:11 every time unless the scanf function is not there.
This is how the .dat file looks like: The column with zeros eventually has real numbers.

```
 1   0.075   1.79    0
 2   0.075   1.84    0
 3   0.075   1.89    0
 4   0.075   1.84    0
 5   0.075   1.73    0
 6   0.075   1.61    0
 7   0.075   1.49    0
 8   0.075   1.35    0
 9   0.075   1.22    0
 10  0.075   1.07    0
 11  0.075   0.98    0
 12  0.075   0.98    0
 13  0.075   0.97    0
 14  0.075   0.97    0
 15  0.075   0.96    0
 16  0.075   0.94    0
 17  0.075   0.93    0
 18  0.075   0.91    0
 19  0.075   0.89    0
 20  0.075   0.86    0
```

I am not sure I understand why is this failing just scanning. I have used the same code to scan files with two columns, and things have worked out. Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Move your arrays to file/global scope to get around what dbush mentioned. Put this _above_ `main`: `#define POINTS 3606930` followed by: `double T[POINTS],A[POINTS],sd[POINTS];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrays `T`, `A`, `sd`, and `n` are local to the `main` function and therefore most likely reside on the stack.  Each of these has 3606930 elements with 3 of type `double` (most likely 8 bytes) and one of type `int` (most likely 4 bytes), so these arrays take up over 100MB of space on the stack.  That is much too large for just about any implementation, so you end up with a stack overflow.

For arrays of this size you should either declare them at file scope so they reside in the data section or allocate memory for them dynamically using `malloc` so they live on the heap.